# Multiple databases in postgres with Kubernetes?

Tags: java, postgresql, kubernetes

I have four java apps (that make up one large java app) that use two postgres servers with about 8 different databases (four on each postgres server).

Since we're going with kubernetes I'm not shure what to do that would yield a good result? Can I make in a consistent way just a single postgres replica with 8 databases in it? Is that even possible in Kubernetes? Maybe there is a better way of handling that situation?

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need your 8 databases on 2 different servers(because of proximity or otherwise), then I would put all 8 databases in a single instance. One less thing to manage.

You can run your postgres database in a single replica(or more than one replica) within Kubernetes. Running a database in a container means you would also need to setup persistent storage, otherwise you will lose data when your container is stopped.

To run a database in Kubernetes with persistent storage, you need to create a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), a [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), and a [persistent volume claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims). I'm using NFS in this example, but there are plenty of other storage options available.

## postgres-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-database
  labels:
    app: my-database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-database
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: postgres:9.6.3
        name: my-database
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z"
          name: postgresdb-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: postgresdb-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgresdb-volume-claim
status: {}
```

## postgres-pvolume.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgresdb-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: postgresdb-class
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  nfs:
    server: <NFS_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>
    path: /var/nfs/data/my-database-data
```

## postgres-pvolume-claim.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgresdb-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: postgresdb-class
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
status: {}
```

Then you can add these to your Kubernetes cluster with the following commands:

```
kubectl create -f postgres-pvolume.yml 
kubectl create -f postgres-pvolume-claim.yml 
kubectl create -f postgres-deployment.yml
```

One word of caution though. Persistent storage in the containerized world is still in its infancy, and can be problematic in high traffic environments when running more than one replica. If you plan on scaling your database(i.e. running more than one postgres replica), you should research this further, before doing anything in production. There are lots of articles on the web about this.

A lot of people still run their databases in VM's, or on bare metal, and only run databases in containers for local development only.

Comment: Yes, I think also that I'm not going to run postgres in a container in production...a lot of unknowns...tnx for the answer!

Comment: There are few things which can be problematic. 1. What if volume crash 2. If data center is in USA then Asia region client will have more latency than USA client. 3. There is only one write in PG database so write can be slow.